How to check if the device is Desktop, Android or IOS in C# .Net Core Razor pages?
Explaination:
I am currently working on VS2022 and Net Core 9.0.
I want to be able to send SMS to the client by clicking on a button.
After the App checks the device type, it selects the right button.
My problem is that Android and IOS have different syntaxes.
Question:
How can i detect if the device is Desktop, Android or IOS? Is there a method to do this?
Code:
To work on Android:
<a href="sms:/* phone number here */?body=/* body text here */">Link</a>

To work on iOS:
<a href="sms:/* phone number here */&body=/* body text here */">Link</a> 


I have been using BlazorBrowserDetect for this.
It has worked pretty well for me and is easy to use, in Blazor.
BlazorBrowserDetect
<BrowserDetect BrowserInfoChanged="OnBrowserInfoChanged"/>
@code {
   private void OnBrowserInfoChanged(BrowserInfo info)
   {
      var isMobile = info?.IsMobile ?? true;
      var isIPhone = info?.IsIPhone ?? false;
   }
}

In Razor, the browserDetect.js file might be helpful:
browserDetect.js

The 'browserDetect.js' does not exist in the Client Side Libraries. Could you kindly explain how to implement it in .net Core Razor Pages?

Review the implementation in browserDetect.js to understand how navigator.userAgent is utilized to extract browser-specific details.
Also check those documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgent

I managed to solve it this way:
0. Library Installation:
Install : Shyjus.BrowserDetector, from the Nuget

1. On Program.cs add:
builder.Services.AddBrowserDetection();

2.The backend code:
       private readonly IBrowserDetector browserDetector; 
   private readonly TEST.Models.DbContext _context;

   public IndexModel(my.DbContext context, IBrowserDetector browserDetector)
   {
       _context = context;
       this.browserDetector = browserDetector;
   }

   [TempData]
   public string GetOS { get; set; } = default!;


   public async Task OnGetAsync()
   {
       GetOS = browserDetector?.Browser?.OS;
   }

3.The Frontend code:
@{

bool ooss = false;
if (Model.GetOS == "Mac OS" || Model.GetOS == "iOS")
{
    ooss = true;
}else
{

}

}
Check if it is IOS:
@if (ooss == true)
{
<a href="tel:+112345678&body=" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark " >
    IOS Sms
</a>

}
else
{
<a href="sms:+112345678?body=" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark " >
    Android SMS
</a>

}
